# Change webpart name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, web-parts, config

I have developed and deploy a webpart into SP2010. I would like make some changes to the webpart and show it to my clients but I need to keep the original webpart in case they dont like the new changes. So I would like to have 2 versions of my webpart on the server but use only one Visual Studio project.

In Visual Studio I made the following changes : 
1. The solution name ( MyWebPart to MyWebPartNew)
2.  The assembly name (from the Properties window of the project) 
3. The MyWebPart.webpart file to MyWebPartNew.webpart
    +  
4. Element.xml

The 'new' webpart is successfully deployed on the server BUT it overwrote my old webpart :( . I looked into the debug output folder and see the dll and pdb file has changed to the new name but not the wsp file.

Have I missed something ? How do I add the new webpart without overwrite the old one from the same project ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easieast way would probably be to add a new webpart next to your old one. In that case you can simply remove the old one if they prefer the new one.

But in your case, I think your problem is that you didn't change your wsp name (double click "package" in Visual studio) and that you didn't change you solution id (guid in properties window after you click package). What happens when you deploy (from Visual Studio) is that is first retract your old solution and then adds the new one resulting in that your old webpart is malfunctioning.

But as I wrote, I would suggest you instead create a new, identical webpart with your changes in it, and deploy it next to you old webpart.